# How to log Just fingerprint of a SSL cert in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I have a spring boot app that uses MTLS for client/server comm. My app talks to about 3 to 4 different SSL enabled servers. Hence, uses a specific HttpClient with specific SSL context to talk to a specific server. Ideally, it has got a client per server. I would like to just log the finger print(or something that would help me to identify the cert used by the client) of the Certificate used by the client while making call to the server. Just wondering is there a simple easy way to extract just this value from the SSL context and log it while making a call to Server. I tried enabling SSL debug logging, which seems to be creating a lot of noise in logs or probably I haven't set up the correct amount of SSL debug config.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can get the SSLSession from the SSLSocket, and get the peer's certificates from that. You can then create a fingerprint from the server certificate.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk I'm using Ktor Client with Apache Engine. I cannot find an easy straight forward way to get hold of the SSL socket or the SSL context.